# Server send events with spring 4.3

Tags: java, spring, server-sent-events

I am trying to do some SSE with spring 4.3, so far Ive found tons of documentation about spring 5 and spring boot 2.0, no luck with my old version 4.3 (I cannot upgrade it)

I was wondering if there is real way to do server side events other than use a cron job (@Schedule)?

Ive found many info of Emmiters but have no sense for me since I dont see any difference (or maybe I cannot implement them properly).

So far I have this:

```
@RequestMapping("/sseTest")
            public ResponseBodyEmitter handleRequest() {
                ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
                service.execute(() -> {
                        try {
                            emitter.send(LocalTime.now().toString(), MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);

                            Thread.sleep(200);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            emitter.completeWithError(e);
                            return;
                        }
                    emitter.complete();
                });

                return emitter;
            }
```

So, if I make a GET to /sseTest it returns the info and that is it, I cannot send more info... I have to close the emitter with emitter.complete() else I will get a timeout some seconds later(so, makes no sense for me use it for SSE from an API to a consumer).

Ive also been reading the reactor project, seems like it is the base for spring 5, but no luck implementing it. https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/

Any idea how to implement any of this with spring 4.3?

Thanks

Comment: SSE is server *sent* events, not server *side* events.

Comment: In this particular instance, the code for spring 4 and spring 5 (and spring-boot 1.5.x and 2.0.x) are pretty much interchangeable -- with some minor reorganization of classes and packages. I've got a method that calls the emitter, which is annotated with `@Async` and it works as expected and didn't require a code change to go from Spring 4 to 5.

Comment: thanks @PeterCordes, you are right, Ive edited my question.... any idea how to deal with them?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I need to be streaming new events from my backend to my consumer without timeouts, is it possible with @Async?

Comment: Async just says don't wait for it. Use Scheduled if you want it to happen periodically. Just have something call your emitter.

Comment: Im doing that @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas but I still get timeout from the client... seems like it doesnt get it as streamer

Comment: No clue, I only saw this question because you mistagged it with [tag:sse]: x86's SIMD instruction-set extensions.  Those of us that follow the vectorization / assembly tags see a few questions a week that we have to retag when people don't check the tag popup text.